# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtension.Client.Fetch.FetchProxy' to type 'Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxFetchProxy'

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to create a report in CRM Online where I am getting the following error.

```
 Unable to cast object of type 
'Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtension.Client.Fetch.FetchProxy' to type 
'Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxFetchProxy'.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Show query that retrieves data for your report

Comment: <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="opportunity" enableprefiltering="1" >
<attribute name="name" />
<attribute name="opportunityid" />
<order attribute="name" descending="false" />
<filter type="and">
<condition attribute="statecode" operator="in">
<value>0</value>
</condition>
</filter>
<link-entity name="new_review" from="new_reviewid" to="new_mostrecentreview"  link-type="outer" alias="MRR">
<attribute name="new_reviewid" />
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>

Comment: How are you editing the report? I compared your query to a working Quote FetchXML query. The main difference I see is that it has the prefilterparametername attribute on the entity node:
    <entity name="quote" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredQuote">